# why jquery ajax method can only make a call to webmethod

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, jquery-ajaxq

While working with jQuery Ajax method, I came to know that the method can only make a call to webmethod or get/post of mvc. Why cannot I call the normal function using ajax method?

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "CS.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
    data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnSuccess,
    failure: function(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

Suppose, I am making a call to the method GetCurrentTime() of CS.aspx page, then i need to decorate the GetCurrentTime() with attribute **WebMethod**, to make a call from ajax method.

Comment: Your question is not clear for me, Do you want to send data using other methods?

Comment: @Kermani please check now, i have included the example and please let me know if its still unclear.

Comment: You are asking about server code issues and showing only client side code. Question is totally unclear. Also have no idea what *"call the normal function"* means. Also note there is no `failure` property in `$.ajax`...see docs

Answer (score 1):

What you get is expected behavior. The issue is not related to jQuery, but rather to the server-side code.

You normally request a resource via its URL to get that resource.

`CS.aspx` is the URL pointing to that page.

Using `CS.aspx/GetCurrentTime` actually is a different URL asking for a different resource.

And this is where `WebMethodAttribute` comes in. It tells ASP.NET that a new resource is available via the URL `CS.aspx/GetCurrentTime` and this way the ASP.NET runtime knows what to do when a request is made for that URL.

As a side note: ASP.NET MVC does not use .aspx in its URLs (not by default, at least). Better check your setup and get your things straight.

EDIT: If you were using MVC, you'd be in a controller (not a page) and you'd be writing actions (not methods). And no WebMethodAttribute would be necessary in that case because, by default, all public actions are available via the URLs configured in the RouteConfig.

The default route is this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Hope this helps clearing your issues.